# Laravel :file can not be submitted

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel `5.5`.
My form can not submit file,as follow:

html：

```
<form action="/profile" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="username">   
    <input type="file" name="photo">                           
    <button type="submit">submit</button>                           
</form>
```

controller：

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('photo');  
    dd($file); //result is  null

    $file = $request->photo;  
     //dd($file);//result is "myphoto.jpg",the name of the file.

    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
      dd('ok');  //not be executed.
    }

}
```

input `username` is ok,file can not be submitted,why is it?
Is it relative to nginx or php config?

Comment: Try to use Laravel Collective form package. It will boost up development speed for CRUD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form

```
<form action="/profile" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```